# Cannot get current location in my weather App.getlatitude() and getlongitude() not working

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, currentlocation

**Android**
In my weather app I cannot get the current location and access its temperature.I think there is no problem with the api cause my weather app is working fine when am typing the city name and searching for weather. however the app is not showing my current locations weather.I also find that the Toast message on Onprovider disabled is being shown.

private void getWeatherForCurrentLocation() {

```
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationListner = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


            String Latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            String Longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            Log.e("state",Latitude);


            RequestParams params =new RequestParams();
            params.put("lat" ,Latitude);
            params.put("lon",Longitude);
            params.put("appid",api);
            letsdoSomeNetworking(params);




        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
           // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"can not get",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(Location_Provider, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, mLocationListner);

}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Location get Succesffully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getWeatherForCurrentLocation();
        }
        else
        {
            //user denied the permission
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's been ages since i last use android studio but i remember that you have to give the permession to use the provider. you have to insert this line in the manifest.xml in the application tag.


in case it don't works after this, check this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element
hopefully useful i don't remember very well.

Comment: try this   always in the manifest.xml delete the other <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: used this but in vain